# How to close a WCF client which resides in a IoC container

Tags: .net, wcf, unity-container, ioc-container, wcf-client

I'm a bit confused on how to close a WCF client properly, which is registered as a singleton in unity.
Here's the code to register the WCF client:

```
//Register service in container
InstanceContext instanceContext = new InstanceContext(new PlatformCallback());
unityContainer.RegisterType<IPlatformInterface, Platform>(
      new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
      new InjectionConstructor(instanceContext));
```

So, this service is registered as as singleton and I'm wondering on how to call the Close() method for this service client.

Without the container, I would open the client when the app starts up and closing it before the app gets closed.

The context here is a WPF application and I'm not sure if the WCF service instance is still valid when the user closes the main window. 
Is it a good idea to resolve the service in the OnExit method of the app and then call Close on it to clean up any resources?

Comment: Why do you want to clean up any resources when your program is exiting anyway?